Manga about a girl who is reborn in the world of her favourite video game as her half elf game character
I can't remember the name of the manga, but I do remember that the main character (MC) is playing her favorite video game when she is trying to find one of the legendary wish granting stones that is hidden in a dungeon. When she finds it, she is reborn into the game world as a baby version of her game character (her character is a half elf with white hair and I believe golden if not red eyes).
Her mother is the elf queen who was dying, but the MC's father who is human finds one of the stones that grants wishes (it's one of the few stones and the same stone the MC found in the dungeon). The MC's father saves the MC's mother who then became human because her elf blood was sealed (elf blood in this manga is mana-infused blood, it is what makes them have a long life span). The MC is born between the elf queen and a human father. After a few years the MC has the all the items she had in the game.
I think it had the first 2 or 3 pages of each chapter colored.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Also, you tagged this "reincarnation" but you seem to be talking about transmigration into a game world, which would be "isekai."

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

the manga is not transmigration its full reincarnation from teen/adult to a baby i read this manga a few years ago and i think it had the first 2 or 3 pages of each chapter colored

Is this Heartwarming Isekai Reincarnation Days: Level Max, Item Carryover! I'm the Strongest Little Girl...?

A young girl dies on Christmas day and is reincarnated into the world of her favorite game as her player character!

A Japanese high school girl is playing an online RPG as an elf character with silver hair and golden eyes. She finds a special item in the game called the legendary jewel, then logs out, goes to bed and dies in her sleep.
She then wakes up in the world of the game as the one-year-old version of her character, Reni Shurm Guora, but she starts at max level, since her game data from her previous life was transferred over.



Her father is a human adventurer and her mother used to be an elf queen, but she was dying as a result of losing her ability to control mana. In order to save her, Reni's father gave her the legendary jewel he found, that was rumoured to grant wishes, and she wished to become human, which cured her illness.



